Moderators: if you are deleting "comments that ought to be answers"
... Please give us some advance warning so we can copy-paste the text into an answer, rather than recreating it.
Or, do that copy paste yourself while crediting us. If we posted it as a comment, we obviously don't care all that much about the SE points, so the fact that the answer would have the moderators name attached to it as the poster is probably not more than a minor nuisance.
(It would be nice if moderators were given a tool that let them click on a comment and have it turned into an answer by the same author. But I get the impression stack exchange is minimizing its investment in improving the system and just spending enough to keep it running.)

I cringe when I see a one line comment that was submitted as a placeholder for a fully formed answer.
Sometimes due to the short form of the comment, the comment is missing key details. In other cases it has major errors.
Sometimes the comment remains, even though the writer does submit an answer.
The other day I saw a comment that had a major error. Since I couldn't down vote a comment, the best course of action was to submit my own answer. I should have followed it up with a request to delete the original comment, but that would have taken too much effort with no guarantee it would be removed.
If the comment stays for a least a couple of hours that should be enough time to copy the couple of sentences into an answer, and then delete the comment. Comments are not to be permanent.

If it's a one-liner, that's one thing. If there's an error, a comment saying so takes very little effort. If it's a comment that turned into an adequate answer halfway through without the author noticing, however, it is annoying to have it vanish; that actually discourages people from answering. I agree, comments are not intended to be permanent. I just think this specific scenario could be handled better.

Someone (rightly) flagged your comment as an "answer in a comment".
I left this comment at 2024-11-11 21:36:06Z and then deleted your comment and the others at 2024-11-12 21:17:50Z, so nearly a full day later.
We don't have any particularly good mechanisms to "set an alarm" to come back to a post later, other than leaving the flag unhandled.

Some of us are trying not to be on stack exchange continuously...  Failing, but trying.

And, frankly, I came very close to interpreting this as the community not wanting my answer, and therefore not rewriting it. You said something about not being your worth your effort to do this another way... Consider that it may not be worth our effort either. If you think the words have value, make some slight effort to preserve them. If you don't, zap, and we will understand it that way. Up to you to decide what you prefer; I'm not a moderator on this board.

As far as I know, there is no way for most of us (any if us?) to see the comment editing history and recover deleted text that way...?

No, there's no way for you to get the comment back after it's deleted. That was why I waited a day. And I understand that deleting it might mean the content never returns. Ultimately the solution is not to post answers as comments :-) Comments are temporary post-it notes: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment

The goal is stack exchange is to get answers. Sometimes comments become answers without our realizing it. You have the choice of encouraging people (not necessarily the comments author) to turn those into answers, or discarding them. I submit the latter does not serve the community well

Well, I did encourage it. I could have waited more time (better for you) or less time (less effort for me). But equally you could have realised it was an answer when you finished writing it.

Shrug. We agree that we disagree about whether you pulled the trigger prematurely.

Note that if three people had flagged the comment (rather than just one), it would have been auto-deleted: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work/17365#17365

I'm not going to argue. You made your decision. I have pointed out that there are consequences. You have decided you are okay with the consequences. Nothing further to discuss.
